# Compiling program with Cygwin - getting the "error: cygwin cannot find -lmpi_cxx."

Tags: cygwin

What can I do with this?

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_cxx
>
> The openmpi package version 3.1.2 no longer contains the mpicxx compiler wrapper, which is present in 3.1.1 packag" written on this site
> https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-09/msg00180.html.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at

https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2018-09/msg00180.html

> mpic++ and mpicxx are just links to opal_wrapper.exe you can reinstate
>   them by yourself